# How to tackle this Ruby candy store homework?

Tags: ruby, class

I have a class in university that asks students to learn three languages in
one semester. Like one is from really old languages such as Haskell, the other one should be from interpreter languages.

So, now I have to learn Ruby, and I need help. Let's say there is class that has

```
class Help
@@array = Array.new
@@count = 0
@store
@chocolate
@candy
@store_code
```

- store is string (name of store)
- chocolate, candy, store_code are integer (price, and code number)

Lets consider that I have an `add` function and call it twice

```
def add (s, i, i, i)
    array = [s, i, i, i]
    count += 1
end

store_a = Help.new
store_a.add (A, 20, 1, 100)
store_b = Help.new
store_b.add (B, 50, 1, 100)
```

Anyway, store_a chocolate price is 20

store_b chocolate price is 50 now

How do I make a function inside of class that calculates average of chocolate price? (I make the count variable for this, but I don't know if I need it or not).

Comment: "really old languagses such as haskell" - lol, Haskell was created in 1990, only 3 years before Ruby.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)".

Comment: Hi GothLoli. Thanks for wanting to post your solution. To do so, please create a self-answer below, such that the question is preserved. This means that the question is not overwritten by the answer, so that future readers may still understand it.

Comment: Downvoted, see above. Will undownvote if the answer is added below - ping me at `@halfer`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be refactored and made shorter, also you can make use of class variables like you mentioned in the question using "@@", but my goal here is to keep it basic so you can start grasping it and slowly moving to more advanced techniques and designs:

```
    class Warehouse
      attr_accessor :products_stores

      def initialize
        @products_stores = []
      end

      def add_product(args)
        @products_stores << args
      end

      def product_price_avg
         avg = 0
         @products_stores.each do |o|
           avg += o[:product].price
         end
         avg / @products_stores.count
      end

    end

    class Store
      attr_accessor :code
      def initialize(code)
        @code = code
      end
    end

    class Chocolate
      attr_accessor :price
      def initialize(price)
        @price = price
      end
    end

    store_a = Store.new(100)
    store_b = Store.new(200)
    cheap_chocolate = Chocolate.new(20)
    expensive_chocolate = Chocolate.new(50)
    warehouse = Warehouse.new
    warehouse.add_product({store: store_a, product: cheap_chocolate})
    warehouse.add_product({store: store_b, product: expensive_chocolate})
    puts warehouse.product_price_avg
```

Comment: def add_product(args)
           @products_stores << { product: args[:product], store: args[:store] }
         end "i dont understand this part"

Comment: I edited the code and removed some redundancy, sorry about that.
@products_stores is an Array, so in that line we are adding a hash, containing the product and the store, to the array.